# How to use http Call or REST enabled API in PowerApps form to do Post Call

Tags: api, powerapps-forms, powerapps-canvas

I have a PowerApps form. I want to do Post operation through external API call upon one button click over the PowerApps Form. I don't want to use the PowerApps triggered Power Automate for this. So, the question here is that Do we have any way We can directly make an Http call from the PowerApps form from the button On Select property?

I am ready to use the custom connector but then the custom connector to be called from the App form only not through Power Automate.

Please help me on this.

Regards,
Kailash

Comment: You can create a custom connector, add it in your app and then directly call custom connector methods from your app without using Power automate flows.